# Barcode scanner plugin is not working in android Marshmallow ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, barcode, ngcordova

I am developing my ionic app using ngCordova. I have installed camera plugin by using,

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

Then, I have installed barcode scanner plugin by using,

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git
```

While running my ionic app it's asking for camera permission. I have allowed the permission also. 
so, I can able to capture the image.

But, by opening the barcode scanner,

```
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
        alert(imageData.text);
        alert("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
        alert("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("An error happened -> " + error);
    });
```

I can able to opening scanner. I am not able to get the result. scanner is not scanning the barcode..

The same plugin is working for me for android 5+ versions.

Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround is to change your target sdk version to 22 (Lollipop) instead of 23 (Marshmallow).

Try this in `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22"/>
</platform>
```

**OR**

For Android `platforms/android`

In `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` change to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

In `platforms/android/prodject.properties` change to:

```
target=android-22
```

For more try following this issue [thread](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/139)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Might be problem of permission !

Comment: I have allowed permission for camera. Is there any permission for barcode scanner also??/\

Comment: Try this @S.M.Priya https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/139#issuecomment-253492329 to be confirm about the permissions

Comment: @JunaidSalaat  I have tried with android permission plugin as well as diagnostic plugins to allow permission for camera. It is allowing permissions to use camera. camera is woring fine for me. scanner only not able to scan..any other solution??